# Setting EditText in Bundle test not working

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

Hi I am practicing how `Bundle savedInstanceState` works in Activity creation and it restoration. I have tried this:

```
private EditText mTextBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        mTextBox.setText("hello");
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState.getString("name"), 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mTextBox.setText(savedInstanceState.geteString("name"));
    }
}

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      outState.putString("name", "Joe");
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

On first `onCreate()` obviously this will set the `EditText` field with "hello" as `savedInstanceState` is null the `if` block will not be executed. When I change the orientation the `Activity` goes through all callbacks and Toast the String in the `if` block, however, it does not set the `mTextBox` with value from `Bundle` passed in. The `EditText` is still set to `hello` instead of `Joe`, however, the `Toast` in if block shows `Joe`.

Can anyone point out why this is not working as my expectation?

Thanks

Comment: arent you supposed to use mTextBox.setText() on 

        name.setText(savedInstanceState.geteString("name"));

part?

Comment: sorry, I have copied my code from AS and changed the variable name here, but missed to change that one and now it is updated. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: you should use https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Thanks for the reference, it looks great to avoid boiler plate codes, but as a beginner I am interested in understanding of the callbacks.

Comment: Try to Log the value on the if block and see how many times the update was called

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact code you have in Android Studio, not an edited version. I can tell that there are some errors in the above code (like `geteString()`) so it's impossible to know if some other transcription mistake is hiding the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening as a result of [`TextView.getFreezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getFreezesText()), which will:

> Return whether this text view is including its entire text contents in
>   frozen icicles. **For EditText it always returns true**.

And some more info from [`TextView.setFreezesText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText(boolean)):

> Control whether this text view saves its entire text contents when
>   freezing to an icicle, in addition to dynamic state such as cursor
>   position. By default this is false, not saving the text. Set to true
>   if the text in the text view is not being saved somewhere else in
>   persistent storage (such as in a content provider) so that if the view
>   is later thawed the user will not lose their data. **For EditText it is
>   always enabled, regardless of the value of the attribute**.

`icicles` is referring to `savedInstanceState`, that's just what it used to be called.

If you'd like to save and restore the text yourself, you could create a custom `EditText` and override `getFreezesText`, something like:

```
public class NonFreezingEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    public NonFreezingEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getFreezesText() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You could also use [`View.post`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
mTextBox.post(() -> mTextBox.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name")));
```

or [`Activity.onRestoreInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mTextBox.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have used onRestoreInstanceState() as it is easier then custom EditText.

Answer (score 1):

You need setText different "hello". see example

```
private EditText mTextBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    mTextBox.setText("hello");
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState.getString("name"), 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mTextBox.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
}
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  mTextBox.setText("Joe");
  outState.putString("name", mTextBox.getText().toString());
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

OR you must override onRestoreInstanceState. Not call onCreate when text not change.

```
  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mTextBox.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
    }
  }
```